# Latin Expression for "From the Stable"?

Tags: idiom

I had a professor in university who told us that there is a latin expression that sounds something "Exa gratium" - meaning "chosen from a (horse) stable", referring to something (e.g. a horse) being chosen arbitrarily from some set of objects.

Does anyone know of such an expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any expression that sounds like that, but I did come across a Medieval Latin word [*catabulum*](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/catabulum) (from the Greek [κατάβολος](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkata%2Fbolos)), which apparently does mean "sty/animal enclosure." (You'll also see the word spelled *captabulum*.)

From there, you could potentially get:

> ***ex catabulo***, from the sty

If you squint, it *kind of* sounds like *exa gratio* (same number of syllables, at least; declined properly—the preposition *ex* takes an ablative, so it would end in -o).

Via Google I found it in a Medieval martyr text—*vidua suscepit a catabolo B. Virum Marcellum*—but it doesn't seem to mean quite what your professor said it should, so this might just be coincidental.